# Increase docker timeout to join a network

Tags: docker

In our environment we use docker swarm to run some jobs heavily consuming ressources. Those get started and end after some time.

We start the the containers using `docker run --rm --memory=18000m --memory-swap=18000m --oom-score-adj=900 -v /some/mount/point:/opt/workspace/mount-point --network someOverlayNetwork --name someName privateRegistry/imagename:version -c "do what to do"`

Sometimes this call fails with

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Could not attach to network someOverlayNetwork: context deadline exceeded.
```

As far I found out `context deadline exceeded` is the generic way of go to say some timeout happened. I also see the error happens quite exactly 20s after the `docker run` command. And it makes sense, there might be quite a lot of things going on in the cluster in terms of load and network load.

I have no problem to wait more time until the next job run starts, but breaking up the job start causes problems for us.

So the question: Is it possible to increase the timeout `docker run` has to enter a network?